# Ivy Bridge or Haswell for Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server

I'm thinking of building a linux server with either Ivy Bridge (3770k) or Haswell (4770k) and run it under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit.

But considering Kernel support for each type of CPUs, which one should I get? Any up-to-date comparison other than http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_4770k_linux&num=1 which is a bit old?

Comment: I don't know much about the Haswell, other than it uses dramatically less power than the Ivy Bridge, (btw is that i7 or i5?) and that it has a callable built in true random number generator in the processor.  I can't remember where I heard about it, in a podcast for sure, but it uses the random pulls of electrons through the semi-transistors, supposedly caused by some unknown laws of physics.  It's kinda cool look it up.  But based on less power consumption alone, I would get the Haswell if you can afford it.

Comment: It's i7. I know about the less power consumption of Haswell (and speed should be marginally better compared to Ivy Bridge at least on a sane OS like Mac or Windows).  The performance begins to be a bit dubious on Linux Kernel, at least as far as my understanding goes -- hence the question.

Comment: Well they seem to like using the Haswell in the System76 laptops.  Maybe do a bit of research on their products (or contact them directly even) and see what kind of difference it's gonna offer you.  And besides, I'm sure the linux kernels will be updated with more and more support for Haswell features down the road.  Not that you wanna do upgrades to your server mid lifecycle, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Read a bit at overclock.net here: http://www.overclock.net/t/1411229/linux-and-intel-haswell-cpus --  sounds like you should go Ivy Bridge for stability.

Comment: I dunno, man. From what I can gather, Linux kernel >=3.5 seems to work better for Haswell (and for Ivy Bridge for that matter). I'm a bit surprised how little information there exists on the web on Haswell.  It just seems people are not so excited about the CPU and there's not many Linux users using it.  I won't be using it for Desktop, so GPU and graphics are irrelevant here though.

Comment: I'm also sorely disappointed at the lack of information available about Haswell, and it's lack of availability from my local major computer parts dealer.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can get either of them as both are well supported by Linux Kernel >=3.5.
2. However, going for Ivy Bridge would be better taking in account the fact that they're comparatively more stable than the Haswell (which use pretty much less power though).
3. I believe that the coming Kernel updates would bring better efficiency with both CPUs.
   It's actually, a personal choice as far as I understand of it, as both are well supported by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Ubuntu 12.04.3 has kernel 3.8 which works good with Haswell and IVB. If you want newer you can always install mainline kernel.